# Unexpected automatic multiple calls to external server using WebClient

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm developping a Spring boot application based on Webflux (Spring boot 3.1.5 and java 17).
It transfers requests from a FrontEnd application to another external application (called external server below).
The FrontEnd calls My Controller.java which calls my Service.java which calls my ClientAPI.java which calls the external server.
I also call another service from another second server (service called DoneService below).
Thus I am a consumer of 2 external servers and a producer of a FrontEnd application.
To perform my test I replaced the frontEnd application by postman.
Thus my Spring boot application is a producer of the FrontEnd but at the same time a consumer of an extrnal application.

My issue is as follows :
On the external server side I can see on its logs that Its service is called 4 times by my springboot application instead of once.
On my side the logs indicate that (See my logs after below):

- I call the external service only once
- the response status from my ClientAPI.java is success. And my input sent to the external server is correctly saved into the external server DB. The server checks on his side if the data has already been inserted in its DB and in that case It rejects the request telling that the data is already registered. This is what I correctly get when I run again my request.
- but the reponse on my Service.java and my Controller.java failed having 400 error code bad request

In order to check that I call 4 times the external application I use postman in order to directly call the external server service. And it is correctly called once with postman.

My Controller.java :

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class Controller {
    private static final String PATH_SERVICE = "/pathservice";

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @PostMapping(path = PATH_SERVICE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<TheResponseClass> mySpringbootService(@RequestHeader("requestId") String requestId,
            @RequestBody @Valid InputData inputData) {
        Mono<TheResponseClass> response = service.save(requestId, inputData);

        response.subscribe(
                status -> log
                        .debug("Controller :  response status = " + status.getResponse().getStatus()),
                error -> log.error(
                        "Controller : The following error happened!"
                                + error));

        return response;

    }
    
}
```

My Service.java :

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    ClientAPI clientAPI;

    @Autowired
    BuilRequestBody builRequestBody;

    @Autowired
    BuildHeaderRequest buildHeaderRequest;
    
    @Autowired
    DoneService doneService;

    @Autowired
    Config config;

    public Mono<TheResponseClass> save(String requestId, @Valid InputData inputData) {

        Mono<TheResponseClass> response = null;

        if (inputData.getClassInfo() != null) {

            response = clientAPI.sendRequest(
                    builRequestBody.buildRequest(inputData),
                    buildHeaderRequest.computeHeader(requestId, config.getHeaderID()));

            response.subscribe(responseResult -> {
                Status resultStatus = responseResult.getResponse().getStatus();
                log.debug("Service : response status = " + resultStatus);

                if (resultStatus == Status.SUCCESS){
                        //Call another service that uses WebClient implementation
                        doneService.notify();
                }

            }, error -> {
                log.error("Service : error happened !"+ error);
            });
        } else {
            TheResponseClass errorResponse = new TheResponseClass();
            errorResponse.setName("name");
            errorResponse.setOperation("operation");
            response = Mono.just(errorResponse);
        }
        return response;

    }

}
```

My ClientAPI.java calling the external server :

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class ClientAPI {
    private WebClient webClient;
    private String serverUrl;

    // Retrieve CustomWebClient built with htts and token management
    @Autowired
    public ClientAPI(@Qualifier("CustomWebClient") WebClient webClient) {
        this.serverUrl = "https://localhost:8456/myServer";
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    public Mono<TheResponseClass> sendRequest(Request bodyRequest, HeaderParameters headerParameters) {
        
    //log.debug("ClientAPI Header : REQUEST_ID = "+headerParameters.getRequestID().toString());
   // other log.debug for multiple headers data...
    
        Mono<TheResponseClass> result = this.webClient.post().uri(this.serverUrl)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .header(HeaderParameters.REQUEST_ID, headerParameters.getRequestID())
                .body(Mono.just(bodyRequest), Request.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(TheResponseClass.class);

        result.subscribe(responseResult -> {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                String jsonOutput = mapper.writeValueAsString(responseResult);
                log.info("ClientAPI : response result = "+jsonOutput);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }, error -> {
            log.error("ClientAPI : The following error happened on response getStatus!", error);
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

My DoneService.java :

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class DoneService {

    @Autowired
    DoneClientAPI doneClientAPI;

    public Mono<DoneData> done(DoneRequest doneRequest) {
        
        return doneClientAPI.sendRequest(doneRequest).flatMap(s -> {
            .....
            return Mono.just(s.getDoneDataList().get(0));
        });

    }

}
```

My DoneClientAPI.java :

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class DoneClientAPI {
    private WebClient webClient;
    private static final String NOTIFY_URI = "/Done";
    private String notificationUrl;


    public Mono<DoneResponseList> sendRequest(DoneRequest doneRequest) {

        return this.webClient.post().uri(this.notificationUrl)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
                .body(BodyInserters
                        .fromFormData(DoneRequest.SYSTEM_ISSUER, DoneRequest.SYSTEM_ISSUER)
                        .with(DoneRequest.DATE_REQUEST, doneRequest.getDate_request()))
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(DoneResponseList.class);

    }
}
```

some of my Simplified data models :

Input Data coming from the FrontEnd:

```java
public class InputData {
    private String Data;
    private ClassInfo ClassInfo;
    
    public void setData(String Data) {
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    public void setClassInfo(ClassInfo ClassInfo) {
        this.ClassInfo = ClassInfo;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return Data;
    }

    public ClassInfo getClassInfo() {
        return ClassInfo;
    }
}
```

The Request data to the external server :

```java
public class Request {

  private String name;
  private String operation;

   public Request() {
  }

  public Request name(String name) {
    
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }
  
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String string) {
    this.name = string;
  }


  public Request operation(String operation) {
    
    this.operation = operation;
    return this;
  }

  public String getOperation() {
    return operation;
  }

  public void setOperation(String operation) {
    this.operation = operation;
  }

}
```

My logs :

```
12:05:38.266 ERROR i.z.b.t.l.b.s.Service - Service : error happened !org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST https://externalServerIP:8456/myServer
12:05:38.401 ERROR i.z.b.t.l.w.controller.Controller - Controller :  The following error happened on getStatus response!org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST https://externalServerIP:8486/myServer
12:05:38.676 ERROR o.s.b.a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler - [506b1d63-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/v1/biometricprofileEnrol"
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST https://externalServerIP:8456/myServer
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:307)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ 400 BAD_REQUEST from POST https://externalServerIP:8456/myServer [DefaultWebClient]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler package.webservice.controller.Controller#mySpringbootService(String, InputData) [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "myServer" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:307)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:214)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorReturn$ReturnSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorReturn.java:162)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:413)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:431)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:485)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:712)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:114)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1466)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1329)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1378)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
12:05:39.041 INFO  p.ClientAPI - ClientAPI : response result = {"name":"yourname","operation":"yourOperation","response":{"status":"SUCCESS","error_Code":null,"system_message":null}}
```

Comment: your problem is that you have misunderstood what `subscribe` does. all backend servers are `producers` and they _produce_ data to the _consumer_ so who is the _consumer_? Well thats the final cconsumer of data, and in your case its the webpage fronted. The frontend `subscribes` to the backend. So the the question is then, why are you subscribing ? its the frontend that subscribes, so `remove all subscribe statements`, and return `Mono`and `Flux` from your controllers.

Comment: Thanx. Indeed I removed all the subsribe statements and I had only one call. BUT this solution does not fit with my requirement. Because I'm also a consumer of another external server at the same time. What can I replace subscribe in Service.java with? I really need to retrieve the result from my WebClient to perform other call to other external services. I tried flatMap() instead of subscribe() but get the same unexpected behaviour i.e several calls. I tried also doOnSuccess() but nothing happens and I cannot  use doOnSuccess().block in my case.

Comment: i cant teach you the basics of webflux, only final consumers should subscribe, when you say "i tried this and i tried that" i cant help you, since i can only provide help on code i see, and the code you have provided is the code in your question. And in your code, you are using subscribe wrongly, thats all i can help with. Stack overflow is not a forum, its a Q/A site. You may be a consumer, of another service but you are not the FINAL consumer. WIthout seeing your code its impossible for me to help you.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding indeed you saved my day with your response. Better understanding of subscribe. 
Better understanding of flatMap as I managed to use it fitting why my requirement.
Thus I clarified my request and wrote an answer with additionnal inputs that I get also on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to Toerktumlare and other inputs, I deleted the subscribe calls that duplicate the call to the external service.
Because I already have an implicit subscribe with my controller calling the external API.
I use flatMap instead in order to manipulate the received data.
I use subscribe to call DoneService as I directly need to call it inside one of my method (not a request coming directly from the FrontEnd through the controller)

Thus for the Controller.java for example :

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class Controller {
    private static final String PATH_SERVICE = "/pathservice";

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @PostMapping(path = PATH_SERVICE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<TheResponseClass> mySpringbootService(@RequestHeader("requestId") String requestId,
            @RequestBody @Valid InputData inputData) {
        return service.save(requestId, inputData);

    }
    
}
```

And for calling my DoneService from Service.java :

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    ClientAPI clientAPI;

    @Autowired
    BuilRequestBody builRequestBody;

    @Autowired
    BuildHeaderRequest buildHeaderRequest;

    @Autowired
    DoneService doneService;


    public Mono<TheResponseClass> save(String requestId, @Valid InputData inputData) {
        Mono<TheResponseClass> response = null;
            // builRequestBody and buildHeaderRequest are used to convert the inputData into the 
            // dedicated format for the external server API 
            return clientAPI.sendRequest(
                    builRequestBody.buildRequest(inputData),
                    buildHeaderRequest.computeHeader(requestId, config.getHeaderID())).flatMap(responseResult -> {
                    Status resultStatus = responseResult.getResponse().getStatus();
                    if (resultStatus == Status.SUCCESS) {
                        ....
                        //Call another service that uses WebClient implementation
                        doneService.notify().subscribe();

                    }
                    return Mono.just(responseResult);
                });
    
    }
}
```